# How to foreach datagrid in a StackPanel in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my `XAML` I have the following `stackpanel` that can contain a list of elements, some of which will be datagrids (some not)

```
    <ScrollViewer Name="MainScrollViewer" Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel Name="MainStackPanel">
            // label
            // datagrid
            // label
            // button
            // datagrid
            // .....
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

And the names of the `datagrids` as well as the number of them is dynamic (I do not know up front).

In my XAML.CS I need to do the following
- for each `datagrid` in my `stackpanel`
  - print it

Now I know how to print (that is not the issue) but I am having a really hard time finding out how to access all the elements in the `stackpanel` and somehow `FOREACH` of the datagrids only ...

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (DataGrid dataGrid in MainStackPanel.Children.OfType<DataGrid>())
{

}
```

OR

```
 foreach (UIElement child in MainStackPanel.Children)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = child as DataGrid;
            if (dataGrid != null)
            {
                //your code here
            }
        }
```

Comment: I suggest being a little more detailed with your answers and explanations. As it stands, this is barely an answer.

Comment: 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `accepting a first argument of type` In the above snippet there is no argument passed to `OfType`. What have you tried, can you show your code?

Comment: since OfType method is an extension method, you should add using System.Linq

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. Not tested, hope it works:

```
    List <DataGrid> dataGridList = new List<DataGrid>();

    for (int i = 0; i < MainStackPanel.Children.Count; i++)
    {
        if (typeof(DataGrid) == MainStackPanel.Children[i].GetType())
        {
            dataGridList.Add((DataGrid) MainStackPanel.Children[i]);
        }
    }

    foreach(DataGrid dg in dataGridList)
    {
        // add your code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See example below.. Since the `StackPanel's` Children property contains a `UIElementCollection`, you can iterate through it, looking for the type of control you need.

```
private StackPanel _stackPanelContainer = MainStackPanel; // Get a reference to the StackPanel w/ all the UI controls

// Since StackPanel contains a "List" of children, you can iterate through each UI Control inside it
//
foreach (var child in _stackPanelContainer.Children)
{
   // Check to see if the current UI Control being iterated over is a DataGrid
   //
   if (child is DataGrid)
   {
       // perform DataGrid printing here, using the child variable
   }
}
```